# How to use SQL Alchemy models the same way than django models

Tags: python, django, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have been using fast api for a few days and passing the `db` session around is starting to bother me a bit. In my previous project I was using a django backend, where to make queries I only needed to import the model. Something like:

```py
from models import SomeModel

class SomeRepository:
    def method(self):
        SomeModel.objects.filter(...)
```

But in fast api, I need to take care of the `db` session object and pass it as argument, something like:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from models import SomeModel

class SomeRepository:
    def method(self, db: Session):
        db.query(SomeModel).all()
```

Is there any way to make fast api and sql alchemy work like the way models work in Django?

Comment: Any reason for not creating your repository with the session? So you'd do `self.db.query(SomeModel).all()` instead, and not having to pass the session around. In FastAPI you'd generally have a `get_some_repository` dependency function, which in turn could have a `Depends` on your `get_db` function, so your controller function gets an already set up and configured repository to work with.

Comment: [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html#) are also an option. But I would prefer @MatsLindh's version (although I would create a service which creates repository to avoid direct access to model layer from controllers layer)

Comment: Whether you call it a service or a repository doesn't really matter; two levels of indirection is probably more than necessary in most cases anyway; especially when coming from Django which by tradition has fat models.